# Is it possible to create an empty file, that loads its contents from a custom API upon opening

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on a file sharing solution, that would allow the use of the shared files (based behing an API) via Windows Explorer, much like the standard Mapped Network Drive functionality. The Mapped Network Drive way enables the user to see&use all files as if they were present on his hard drive, but they are actually not. Is there a way to enable similar functionality with a custom web API being the source of the file contents, especially the "not present locally" part? The important part being, that the contents are not stored locally, just available on request.

Something along the lines:

1. A file stub is created locally within the same folder structure and the same name (empty, perhaps some additional information in the properties of the file)
2. Upon users opening of the file (request) the contents are transfered to the local file system
3. The file is opened using the default application for specific
   format.

Thanks,

Comment: That is possible, yes.

Comment: You will likely need to create your own extension and your own URI protocol to handle the click of the small/empty file you are describing.

Comment: The [CloudMirror sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror) shows how to dynamically provide content from a cloud service, and the [Projected FileSystem](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/ProjectedFileSystem/) shows how to dynamically provide content algorithmically.